# European postal code shapes provider

Tags: shapefile, geojson, zip-codes, postal-code, boundaries

I am looking for a single (paid) provider of postal (zip) code shapes (boundaries) for countries in Europe. I hope to find reliable partner with reasonable pricing and update policy. What I need are polygons (shp and shx, or geojson format) to draw service coverages and host it in commercial web application.

Comment: Mapbox can provide this for you.

Comment: That may not be entirely possible. I don't know about other countries, but for instance in The Netherlands, the official zipcodes are defined as points. There is no such thing as a zipcode polygon. (The local Esri distributor provides zipcodes as polygons for free, but these are interpolated points, and have some strange artifacts here and there)