# Looking for a shapefile for Europe on 4-digit postal code

Tags: shapefile, data, postal-code, europe

I am looking for a source of a shapefile hat includes european countries with 4-digit postal codes.

The country codes should be DIN-A2 (two digit) and a postal code for four digits...

Does anyone have an idea where to find such a file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the country codes should be DIN-A2 (two digit) and a postal code for four digits...

Comment: Please include this information into the question by editing it instead of commenting.

Comment: For open data (or any data) the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You (incorrectly) assume that all postal codes in Europe have the same format.

Although 4-digit postal codes are common, there are also a lot of countries that use 5 (Germany, France, Italy, etc.). Of course this is highly correlated with the size of the country in question. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes) for a list of postal code formats.

As to answer your question: I think you will have a very hard time to find one data source for all postal code areas in Europe, as this is a local and policy-based convention. If you really need this aggregation level -for a specific reason- then I'm afraid you will have to create this data set yourself. Most nations have their own GIS sources, which you will have to find out, but -for example- ESRI might have a lot of these available as well. I know for a fact that [ESRI NL](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=63ebde0ca12449e5a3a1a3034711d608#overview) provides the Dutch postal code areas.

See also [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176685/european-postal-code-shapes-provider) on SE, which implies that these kinds of data sets are paid services.

Comment: Not to mention the UK which has alphanumeric postcodes (e.g. BN12 4SG) and the privatised postal service owns the postcode geography.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense of course... Then again, any suggestions for a source for Austria, Poland or Czech Republic? 

Thanks for your help!